# In the field of exploring the fusion of pragmatics and semantics, which scholars and papers are worth paying attention to?

Tags: philosophy-of-language

In the field of exploring the fusion of pragmatics and semantics, which scholars and papers are worth paying attention to? For example, I'm interested in John Perry's "Belief Semantics" and Dr. Maria Aloni's "Nothing is Logical."

Answer (score 3):

I would consider something along these lines (google helps of course):

1. Laurence R. Horn: "Toward a New Taxonomy for Pragmatic Inference: Q-based and R-based Implicature" (1984) "Implicature" in The Handbook of Pragmatics (2004)
2. Francois Recanati: "Literal Meaning" (2004) "Pragmatics and Semantics" in The Routledge Companion to Philosophy of Language (2012)
3. Kent Bach: "Conversational Impliciture" (1994) "Speech Acts and Pragmatics" in The Blackwell Guide to the Philosophy of Language (2003)
4. Robyn Carston: "Thoughts and Utterances: The Pragmatics of Explicit Communication" (2002) "Metaphor: Ad Hoc Concepts, Literal Meaning and Mental Images" (2010)
5. Deirdre Wilson and Dan Sperber: "Relevance Theory" in The Handbook of Pragmatics (2004) "Meaning and Relevance" (2012)
6. Eros Corazza and Kepa Korta: "Strict and Defective Quotation" (2021)
7. Laurence R. Horn and Barbara Abbott: "Implicature" in The Cambridge Handbook of Pragmatics (2012)
8. Yan Huang: "Pragmatics" (2014)